# How can I dry my hair more quickly?

Tags: hair

It is super annoying to have hair dripping onto my clothes after taking a shower. Because I don't want my hair wet, I need a faster way to dry my hair.

I have already tried

- Blow drying
- Shaking my head over the shower
- Quickly moving the towel on my hair

These methods seem to be slow.

My hair is straight, and each piece is about 1 inch.

Comment: How dry are you talking about? Approximately how much time is too slow? I have about the same hair length and drying it with my towel works well and is quite fast, usually dries enough for my taste in about thirty seconds.

Comment: Try wringing out your hair?

Comment: With one inch hair, I don't understand how your aren't getting it dry to the point it doesn't drip. Take a dry towel, vigorously use it on your head, done. And always dry yourself from the top down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have *quite* long hair and this is what works for me 847% as minimum:

Before you do any drying operations with your hair, wipe your head with some towel (personally I don't like it when water is dripping from my hair),  lower your head so that all the hair is drooping down:

> [image]
>
> <sup>maybe its not really beautiful, but my freehand!</sup>

Then, if you have (I hope you do) a circular comb, like this

> [image]
>
> [source](http://img.alibaba.com/img/pb/670/733/382/382733670_310.jpg)

Reel your hair up with it while fanning it, starting from the roots. If you don't have such a comb, use the usual one, but the circular is more effective.

Also, if there is someone with me and I am using public fans and there are almost no people, I ask that *someone* to use another fan (while I am using the first) :)

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

- Brush your hair out and give it more surface area by brushing. Then dry with a  towel or blow dryer.
- Tie a towel around your head or shoulders. Also, shake the hair off while you are in the shower.
- Take your hair and wrap it around the towel and then twist it dry. This might not work for shorter hair that well, but I know it works for long hair.
- Rubbing your head vigorously with the towel while alternating rubbing sideways and circular movements, this is good for short hair and this also makes the hair appear soft.
- Putting a dedicated cap on your head will make sure no water gets on you and the hair gets dry.  Also, shower caps are waterproof caps that stop the hair from getting wet.

**Using several of these tactics at once increases effiency.**

[Good House Keeping:](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/beauty/hair/how-to-speed-dry-hair)

> Switch to a ceramic round-barreled brush. It conducts heat and will
>   warm up under the hot airflow of your dryer, reducing blowout time,
>   says Sean Jahanbigloo, co-owner of Juan Juan Salon in Los Angeles.
>   "These brushes usually have fewer bristles than ones made of boar hair
>   (often used for blowouts), allowing for more airflow." Try Goody Blow
>   Dry Protect Brush ($9.50, Walmart).

- Use a better Hair Dryer.
- Use your hair care Product on your head after doing a brush. And then try drying with the towel or blow dryer.

---

**Additional Info**

[How to Air Dry Thick Hair](http://www.wikihow.com/Air-Dry-Thick-Hair)

[How to Make Hair Dry Faster Without a Blow Dryer](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Hair-Dry-Faster-Without-a-Blow-Dryer)

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem drying the hair faster, or circumventing the water dripping onto your clothes?

I simple place a towel over my shoulders to avoid the wet shirt situation, and then dry my hair as needed from there. It doesn't speed up the process of drying, but it eliminates the wet shoulder issue.

Comment: You put a shirt on before you dry your hair?

Comment: I don't ... OP seems to per their question. My experience is wet shoulders, but my method would solve wet clothes as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magical hair drying machine just yet, so you will have to stick to the towel/hair dryer, however implementing the following steps will guarantee to dry your hair quicker.

1. Always use conditioner after you shampoo, this will seal some moisture in your hair which helps keep it healthy. The conditioner will also lock the pores in your hair preventing any unnecessary water absorption making the task of drying a lot quicker and easier.
2. Once you've washed your hair, whilst still in the shower/bath give your head a quick shake so there is no unwanted 'drippage' then tip your head upside-down and run your fingers through it so the hair is divided into separate sections and twist each section, wringing out any further excess water.

By just grabbing a towel and drying your hair without performing steps 1 and 2, your towel won't be completely effective (for longer hair). Once a certain degree of moisture has been absorbed by the towel , finding a dry spot can be scarce and the current moisture on the towel won't allow any more to be absorbed. Once you have performed 1 and 2 procede with the towel drying with ends of your finger tips in a rotating motion, dividing the hair as much as possible.

3. Blow dry your hair once section at a time, starting with the root. Whilst blow drying move your fingers through your hair and ruffle your hair constantly, dividing the hair up makes drying a lot quicker. If you prefer to use a brush, use a wide-tooth one so it's easy enough to run through consistently. I would also recommend blow drying with a quick dry product i.e. [KMS California Free Shape Quick Blow Dry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005JDPS7I).

Product recommendations: Microfiber towel and microfiber brush